# Exposing TFS and SharePoint 2010 over the internet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sharepoint, team-foundation-server

I've been trying to find informations about how to expose an installation of Team Foundation Server 2010, Reporting Services 2008 and SharePoint 2010 over the internet, but I haven't succeeded yet. Therefore this question...

Users should be able to login using a personal username and password. They shoule be able to access TFS 2010 from Visual Studio, SharePoint from a browser and SharePoint Workspaces.

What are the pros and cons of doing this over the internet, compared to a domain joined local network?

Do you know of any resources on this subject? Tips, best practices, security issues, etc. Anything will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Anything like this: http://www.tjopsta.net/index.php/2010/04/16/how-to-change-team-foundation-server-2010-urls-for-use-externally/